# Sublime text 2 - compile and run single java file

Tags: java, sublimetext, sublimetext2

How can achieve a simple compile and run functionality for a single(currently open) java source file in sublime text, I am not going for package management and stuff , just a simple run button which compiles and run current java file, sort of like coderunner have.

Comment: see [this](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4805) forum discussion on this same topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [shazeline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461452/shazeline) a way is discussed [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4805), although not ease of use for one-off trying but still something